# How is the amount of displacement calculated?

Tags: rendering, displacement, units

I need to know how blender calculates the amount of displacement it applies to a vertex.

I use the following configuration:

- Cycles renderer
- displacement node (scale = 1.0, midlevel = 0.5)
- 8-bit displacement map

What is the minimal and maximal displacement for this configuration?

My assumption (BU = Blender Unit):

<s>`Min = scale * ( 1 BU / (0 - 128) )`</s>

<s>`Max = scale * ( 1 BU / (255 - 128) )`</s>

Can anyone confirm my assumptions? Unfortunately, there is no information regarding this topic in the official [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/displacement.html).

**Edit: New assumption with some evidence**

- convert values displacement map from range 0...255 to 0.0...1.0
- `displacement = scale * 1BU * (val - midlevel)`

**Experiment for Evidence:**

- I have placed a cube beside my flat surface. ( default cube with 
  edge length of 2BU, therefore scaled z by 0.5)
- edited the displacement map -> added a completely white and a completely black area

**Result:**
[image]

As you can see, the maximal displacement is one BU, as the cube is 1 BU in height. With midlevel 0.5 the displacement spans the range from -0.5 to 0.5.